# Inject multiple log4j logger type using CDI in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, log4j, cdi

I've multiple `RollingFileAppender` in my log4j Config file in order to manage different log types. 
here is my **LoggerFactory** Class :

```
public class LoggerFactory {

    static {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint ip) {
        return Logger.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }

    @Produces
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.CRITICAL)
    public Logger produceCriticalLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger("critical");
    }

    @Produces
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.SERVICE_TIMING)
    public Logger produceServiceTimingLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger("serviceTiming");
    }

    @Produces
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.HEALTH)
    public Logger produceHealthLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger("health");
    }

    @Produces
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.HTTP_HEADER)
    public Logger produceHttpLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger("httpHeader");
    }

    @Produces
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.POSTED_REQUEST)
    public Logger producePostRequestLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        System.out.println(" ********* getAnnotated" + injectionPoint.getAnnotated());
        System.out.println(injectionPoint.toString());

        return Logger.getLogger("postedRequest");
    }

    @Produces
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.DB_TIMING)
    public Logger produceDbTimingLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger("dbTiming");
    }

    @Produces
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.STACK_TRACE)
    public Logger produceStackTraceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger("stackTrace");
    }

    @Produces
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.TRANSACTIONAL)
    public Logger produceTransactionsLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger("transactions");
    }
}
```

and here is my **Annotation** :

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface LogType {

    LoggerType loggerType();

    public enum LoggerType {
        CRITICAL,
        DB_TIMING,
        HEALTH,
        HTTP_HEADER,
        POSTED_REQUEST,
        SERVICE_TIMING,
        STACK_TRACE,
        TRANSACTIONAL
    }
}
```

and here is my **injection point**

```
   @Inject
    @LogType(loggerType = LogType.LoggerType.HEALTH)
    public transient Logger logger;
```

i get this error :

```
 Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @LogType
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @LogType public transient myclass.logger
```

**Additional information** :
there are more injection point in my project and they work fine, i'm sure about WELD library health... and i see the beans icon in my IDE that links me to the producer method. but still i cant find the problem !
 **Question**:
what is the best practice to implement multiple logger type using CDI ?

Comment: None of the code you have shown defines or references `@Loggers`

Comment: @steve-c , it's was refactored from `@Loggers` to `@LogType`

Comment: Why is the structure of your application? Is it a simple WAR or is it an EAR file?

Comment: my application is a kind of Enterprise "multi modules maven project", and so it's EAR.
the problem solved when i moved the **beans.xml** file from EJB module to my Web module.

Answer (score 0):

Maker your producer class `LoggerFactory` a CDI Bean. In your example, it is a simple class without ani CDI annotations. You could for example make it @ApplicationScoped or use any other suitable scope.

Alternatively, you can set bean discovery mode to "all" in beans.xml. This way, even unannotated beans are discovered during application startup.